# default cache-control headers in nextjs SSR

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, cache-control

I have `nextjs` app. If I add `getServerSideProps` export to the page (this means that page will be server side rendered, [read more](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)) `nextjs` adds `cache-control` header:

```
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

But according to this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#preventing_storing) these are conflicting headers and in theory it should be the same as `no-store` header. Citing the acticle:

```
# conflicted
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

# equivalent to
Cache-Control: no-store
```

Is there any reason these multiple headers are used instead of simply using `no-store`?

Comment: Part of it is that, at one point, browsers were inconsistent with each other and with the specification, and different-but-redundant headers were needed to get them all to do the right thing. I imagine that's no longer the case, but I don't know. Since people will blindly repeat code they saw somewhere without really understanding it, the redundant headers will continue to be used in any case.